# Error happens on an insert on a Custom Tag

Tags: tag

I have enabled `Tags` on a Custom Object and I am trying to insert a Tag by a following code

```
insert new CustomObject__tag(Type='Public',ItemId='a0023000000DtDuEAK',name='Custom Tag' );
```

When I execute the code I receive an error

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
> error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient
> access rights on cross-reference id: []"

Usually this happens when a user doesn't have a Read permission to the corresponding record, but I am the owner of the record and have full access permission to custom object record.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Once `Topics` are enabled, Public tags are deactivated.
To workaround this problem, a private tag can be created by using the following code

```
insert new CustomObject__tag(Type='Personal',ItemId='a0023000000DtDuEAK',name='Custom Tag' );
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accounttag.htm

```
Defines the visibility of a tag.
Valid values:
Public — The tag can be viewed and manipulated by all users in an organization.
Personal — The tag can be viewed or manipulated only by a user with a matching OwnerId.
```